# Configuring the Python interpreter so that it stops executing a list of commands whenever one command fails

Tags: python

I sometimes paste  a list of commands to be executed in the Python interpreter ([Interactive Mode](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/appendix.html#tut-interac)  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170816015345/https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/appendix.html))). By default, if one command fails (i.e., raises an error), the Python interpreter indicates the command has failed, then executes the subsequent commands.

Is there any way to configure the Python interpreter (Interactive Mode) so that it stops executing a list of commands whenever one command fails?

---

Answering the comments:

- I am interested in Linux, Mac OS X and Microsoft Windows.
- Code example that I paste in the Python interpreter:

  ```
  1/0
  print('yo')
  ```

  I don't want `yo` to be printed, since `1/0` raises an error.
- I paste the list of commands, from the clipboard, to the Python interpreter

Comment: "a list of commands to be executed in the Python interpreter" - how ? which OS ? can you provide an example ?

Comment: @alfasin question updated.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question: how do you run these "list of commands" ?  if you're saving these list of commands in a file.py and call it with "python file.py" the last command to execute will be 1/0 - in your example.

Comment: @alfasin I paste the list of commands, from the clipboard

Comment: I assume you're referring to "Interactive mode" ?

Comment: @alfasin That's correct, thanks for the clarification

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt If you're not talking about pasting code, you can run a script with python -i script.py. It'll error out and go into interpreter mode so you can debug.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend [`InteractiveConsole`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/code.html#code.InteractiveConsole) and create your own shell which bails out on error. You can even run it from within interactive-mode :)

Here's a small example:

```
from code import InteractiveConsole
import sys


class Shell(InteractiveConsole):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stdout = sys.stdout
        InteractiveConsole.__init__(self)
        return

    def runcode(self, code):        
        try:
            exec code in self.locals
        except:
            self.showtraceback()
            sys.exit(1)  # <-- this is the secret sauce!


if __name__ == '__main__':
     sh = Shell()
     sh.interact()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> sh = Shell()
>>> sh.interact()
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jan 26 2016, 22:37:40)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(Shell)
>>> 1
1
>>> 1+1
2
>>> 1/0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
alfasi:~/Desktop >
```

Comment: Nice answer! It doesn't keep the interactive session running though, which I think is the aim here.

Comment: I hope you don't mind I've borrowed heavily from your answer in an attempt to keep the interactive session going, but ignore subsequent pasted commands. :) Let me know if you'd prefer an edit to your answer.

Comment: @AndrewGuy I don't think he wants to keep the interactive session - the question is around bailing out on the first error. Keeping the session is the *default* behavior which the OP wanted to get rid of.

Comment: You may be right. Hopefully OP will chime in. I *thought* he meant that he wanted to keep the session open, but ignore the rest of the commands that were pasted in. But doesn't seem so clear after re-reading.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to fix this on a standard Python REPL, but you can definitely achieve this with IPython.

In IPython, when you paste code, it is treated as a single code block, rather than a bunch of individual statements.

For example, open an IPython interactive session on your terminal and paste this:

```
x = [1]
y = [1 for _ in range(100)]] # <------ SyntaxError
z = x + y
```

This is what it looks like when pasted:

```
In [136]: x = [1]
     ...: y = [1 for _ in range(100)]]
     ...: z = x + y
```

Now hit enter:

```
  File "<ipython-input-136-20c7b020310a>", line 2
    y = [1 for _ in range(100)]]
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In contrast, on the standard REPL interpreter:

```
>>> x = [1]
>>> y = [1 for _ in range(100)]]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    y = [1 for _ in range(100)]]
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> z = x + y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing heavily from @alfasin's answer, you can extend the `InteractiveConsole` class.

To keep the interactive session running, but ignore the rest of the pasted commands, you can discard the input for a short while (I've used 1 second) after an exception. This means that the rest of the pasted commands are ignored, while leaving you with the session still running.

```
from code import InteractiveConsole
import sys
import time

WAIT_TIME = 1

class Shell(InteractiveConsole):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stdout = sys.stdout
        InteractiveConsole.__init__(self)
        return
    def runcode(self, code):        
        try:
            exec(code, self.locals)
        except SystemExit:
            raise
        except:
            self.showtraceback()
            t_end = time.time() + WAIT_TIME
            while time.time() < t_end:
                _ = self.raw_input()  # Extra pasted commands are discarded


if __name__ == '__main__':
     sh = Shell()
     sh.interact()
```

Note that the extra commands are still printed to the terminal, but aren't actually run.